# Fetching unconditionad sum and conditioned in a single SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a database

```
create table payments (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  amount int,
  source varchar(255),
  dest varchar(255),
);
```

Is it possible to fetch data in a single query in a way so for each dest I'll have a row with SUM of all amounts, and SUM of amounts where source='XXX'.

Comment: Do you want one row or two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` in sum also for your specific condition so this will give you the sum of amounts per `dest` and `sum_xxx` will have a sum of amounts per `dest` where source is xxx

```
select dest,
sum(amount) dest_sum,
sum(case when source ='xxx' then amount else 0 end) sum_xxx
 from payments 
group by dest
```

Comment: Thanks, I havn't thought that case could be used inside sum statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
select dest, (select sum(amount) from payments where source = 'XXX'), sum(amount) from payments 
where source = 'XXX' group by dest;
```